# New ability to move a type to another namespace is missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, namespaces, refactoring

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/move-type-to-namespace?view=vs-2017) seems to indicate that the ability to move a type to another namespace is finally native to Visual Studio -- and should be available in VS 2017 (as the URL indicates).

[image]

But this is all I see in the refactor menu:

[image]

How do I enable this behavior?

Comment: When the going goes tougher , #Resharper for the rescue.

Have you tried Ctrl R, Ctrl O ?

Comment: But we were sooo close ! :)

Comment: I am still dreaming of the day I will say goodbye to #Resharper because my visual has everything I need natively. Switching to VS 2019, I thought dreams would be over. Lo and behold, I am still dreaming...